# How trigger function when specific state changed

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm looking for a way to associate a function with a change in a particular state.

I've written this code

```
export type MoviesAppState = {
    search: string;
    searchBy:string;
    startDate: number;
    endDate: number;
}

export class App extends React.PureComponent<{}, MoviesAppState> {
    startDate = (new Date("2018-11-13")).getTime();
    endDate = new Date().getTime()

    state: MoviesAppState = {
        search: '',
        searchBy:"Select one",
        startDate: this.startDate,
        endDate: this.endDate,
    }

     onSearch = async (val: string, newPage?: number) => {
        clearTimeout(this.searchDebounce);

        this.searchDebounce = setTimeout(async () => {
            let newMovies = await api.getMovies(val, this.state.searchBy, this.state.startDate, this.state.endDate);

            this.setState({
                movies: newMovies,
                search: val
            });
        }, 300);
    }
    startDateChanged = (date: Date) => {
        const startDateTimestamp = new Date(date).getTime()
        this.setState({
            startDate: startDateTimestamp,
        });
    }

    endDateChanged = async (date: Date) => {
        const endDateTimestamp = new Date(date).getTime()
        this.setState({
            endDate: endDateTimestamp,
        });
    }

    onSearchBy = (searchByCriterion:string)=>{
        this.setState({
            searchBy: searchByCriterion
        });
    }

    render() {

        return (<main>
            <h1>Movies</h1>

            <div>
                <header>
                    <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." onChange={(e) => this.onSearch(e.target.value)} />
                </header>


                <SearchByCriterion 
                    searchByHandler={this.onSearchBy}
                    initialCriterion={this.state.searchBy}
                />
            </div>

            <div>
                <span>Start date: </span><MyDatePicker initialDate={this.startDate} dateChangeHandler={this.startDateChanged} ></MyDatePicker>
            </div>

        </main>)
    }
}

export default App;
```

Basically what I want is that onSearch method will fire when one of the things happens- startDateChanged or endDateChanged and not only when the search input changed
I thought about calling it within the methods and I get what I want but I feel it's not the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook, which runs whenever there's a `props` or `state` change and allows you to compare the change before taking an action. See [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

It should look something like this

```js
componentDidUpdate(_prevProps, prevState) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.state.startDate !== prevState.startDate || 
      this.state.startDate !== prevState.startDate) {
    this.search();
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe you meant to say `componentDidUpdate` since `componentDidMount` runs only once and ***not*** when either of `state` or `props` updates.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Glad it helped. Can you give it an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidUpdate` is what you are after: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

```
componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
  const {startDate, endDate, searchBy} = this.state
  if(startDate !== prevState.startDate || endDate !== prevState.endDate || searchBy !== prevState.searchBy){
  // trigger onSearch
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I'm looking for